# How to save and retrieve more than one value in sharedpreferences?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I have 2 activities
1.Register.java
2.SecureXActivity.java
In Register activity i am doing registration of my application using shared preferences. I have used shared preferences to show Register activity only once. Now my requirement is take 
user name from register activity which will be shown only once at the time of registration and save it in SecureXActivity activity, after the registration only this activity will be visible to user. So please help me in this regard? I am new to android.

My code is given below

Register.java

```
public class Register extends Activity
{
public static final String PREFS_NAME = "LoginPrefs";
public static final String USER_NAME = "USER";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.register);

    /*
     * Check if we successfully logged in before.
     * If we did, redirect to home page
     */
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    if (settings.getString("logged", "").toString().equals("logged")) 
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Register.this, SecureXActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);
    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            EditText username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.reg_employeeid);
            EditText password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.reg_password);
            String welcm ="Welcome";
            String space = " ";
            EditText firstname = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.reg_firstname);
            EditText lastname = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.reg_lastname);
            String getfirstname = firstname.getText().toString();
            String getlasttname = lastname.getText().toString();
            String welcome=welcm.concat(space).concat(getfirstname).concat(space).concat(getlasttname);





            if(username.getText().toString().length() > 0 && password.getText().toString().length() > 0 ) 
            {
                if(username.getText().toString().equals("test") && password.getText().toString().equals("test")) 
                {
                    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                    editor.putString("logged", "logged");
                    editor.commit();    
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Register.this, SecureXActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("name", welcome);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

SecureXActivity.java

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new exceptionHandler(this));
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Bundle extras =getIntent().getExtras();

    if (extras != null)
    {
        String value = extras.getString("name");
        TextView txtwelcm= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewwelcm);
        txtwelcm.setText(value);
    }
}
```

I want a value from one activity to another activity and value should be saved to another activity. In my above code i have done this using intent. But the problem is value is shown only once in second activity. Value is not visible when i press back button or home key?How to do this.

Added in response to @Picarus:

The problem is i am using same shared preferences to show the register activity only once. 
But it not showing the name on SecureX activity.Is it possible to use same shared preference to carry value from register activity to securex activity

The Entire code is Given below once again 
Register.java

```
    public class Register extends Activity 
    { 
public static final String PREFS_NAME = "LoginPrefs"; 


@Override 
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)  
{ 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    setContentView(R.layout.register); 

    /* 
     * Check if we successfully logged in before. 
     * If we did, redirect to home page 
     */ 
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0); 
    if (settings.getString("logged", "").toString().equals("logged"))  
    { 
        Intent intent = new Intent(Register.this, SecureXActivity.class); 
        startActivity(intent); 
    } 

    Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRegister); 
    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()  
    { 
        public void onClick(View v) { 
            EditText username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.reg_employeeid); 
            EditText password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.reg_password); 
            String welcm ="Welcome"; 
            String space = " "; 
            EditText firstname = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.reg_firstname); 
            EditText lastname = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.reg_lastname); 
            String getfirstname = firstname.getText().toString(); 
            String getlasttname = lastname.getText().toString(); 
            String welcome=welcm.concat(space).concat(getfirstname).concat(space).concat(getlasttname); 





            if(username.getText().toString().length() > 0 && password.getText().toString().length() > 0 )  
            { 
                if(username.getText().toString().equals("test") && password.getText().toString().equals("test"))  
                { 
                    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0); 
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit(); 
                    editor.putString("name", welcome); 
                    editor.commit();     
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Register.this, SecureXActivity.class); 
                    //intent.putExtra("name", welcome); 
                    startActivity(intent); 
                } 
            } 
        } 
    }); 
} 
}
```

SecureXActivity.java

```
public class SecureXActivity extends Activity 
{ 
public static final String PREFS_NAME = "LoginPrefs"; 

private ListView m_listview; 
Button btnSendlogs; 
Button btnMailadmin; 
Button btnContactSupport; 
Button btnSettings; 

@Override 
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{ 
    Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new exceptionHandler(this)); 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    setContentView(R.layout.main); 
    //Here we are setting the installation date of a application 
    ContextWrapper context = this; 
    PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager(); 
    ApplicationInfo appInfo; 
    try 
    { 
        appInfo = packageManager.getApplicationInfo("com.simsys.securex", 0); 
        String sourceDir= appInfo.sourceDir; 
        long dateTimeSync= new File(sourceDir).lastModified(); 
        String DateTimeStamp=getDate(dateTimeSync, "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss"); 
        String dateTimeSync2="Installed_Date:"; 
        String dateTimeSync3=dateTimeSync2.concat(DateTimeStamp); 
        TextView txtCurrentTime= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewdatetime); 
        txtCurrentTime.setText(dateTimeSync3); 
    }  
    catch (NameNotFoundException e)  
    { 
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    } 
    //Here We Welcome the user 

    //List View 
    m_listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view); 
    ArrayList<String> listItems=new ArrayList<String>(); 
    listItems.add("CAMERA"); 
    listItems.add("RECORDER"); 
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = 
            new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listItems); 

    m_listview.setAdapter(adapter); 
    if(isBluetoothServiceRunning()) 
    { 
        listItems.add("BLUETOOTH"); 
    } 
    if(isGprsServiceRunning()) 
    { 
        listItems.add("GPRS"); 
    } 
    if(isWifiServiceRunning()) 
    { 
        listItems.add("WIFI"); 
    } 
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); 
    //Call to Buttons Functionality 
    btnSendlogs = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_sendlogs); 
    btnSendlogs.setOnClickListener(myhandler1); 
    btnMailadmin=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button_mailtoadmin); 
    btnMailadmin.setOnClickListener(MailadminHandler); 
    btnContactSupport = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_contactsupport); 
    btnContactSupport.setOnClickListener(ContactSupportHandler); 

} 

//Navigation from Registration to Main page 
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)  
{ 
    MenuInflater Inflater = getMenuInflater(); 
    Inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu); 
    return true; 
} 

@Override 
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
{ 
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.logout) 
    { 
        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0); 

        String data2=settings.getString("name", ""); 
        TextView txtwelcm= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewwelcm); 
        txtwelcm.setText(data2); 
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit(); 
        editor.remove("name"); 
        editor.commit(); 
        finish(); 
    } 
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item); 
}
```

Comment: Not sure about what is your specific doubt. Could you clarify? You can have as many settings in Shared Preferences as you need and you can have as many different files as you wish... If you clarify we will be able to help you.

Comment: I want a value from one activity to another activity and value shoud be saved to another activity. In my above code i have done this using intent. But the problem is value is shown only once in second activity. Value is not visible when i press back button or home key?

Comment: What is the problem you are facing . You are using shared preferences then what you are trying to get from it.

Comment: go through http://alchemiaandroid.altervista.org/sharedPreferencesTutorial.html this for better understanding about sharedpreferences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For implementing sharedPreferences use following code

```
 Sharedpreferences myPref = this.getSharedPreferneces("your_file_name",MODE);
 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = myPref.edit();
 editor.putString("String_Name",value);
 editor.putInt("Int_Name","value");
```

To retrieve from SharedPreferences

```
   Sharedpreferences myPref = this.getSharedPreferneces("your_file_name",MODE);  
   String stringValue = myPref.getStirng("String_Name","DEFAULT_VALUE");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve your SharedPreferences from any activity(SecureXActivity) just the same way you do it in Register.java

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
settings.getString("logged", "");
```

have you tried? What is the problem you find?

edit:maybe it´s due to the fact that you have tried to load it from the onCreate. This will not be called when you refresh or click home. you should find a more appropriate point to do it in your app.